# Getting error in pruning apriori rules in grocery dataset

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I'm trying to prune the rules that created by apriori algorithm for groceries dataset but getting one error

Using R 3.4.2 and RStudio (Version 1.1.383)

Imported libraries

```
library(arules)
data("Groceries")
```

I have created the rules

```
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter = list(supp =0.001,
                                         conf = 0.5,
                                         target = "rules"))
```

Started pruning redundant rules

```
rules.sorted = sort(rules, by="lift")
subset.matrix <- is.subset(rules.sorted, rules.sorted)
```

While coverting lower triangle of the matrix to NA I got one warning

```
subset.matrix[lower.tri(subset.matrix, diag=T)] = NA
```

Warning message:

```
In `[<-`(`*tmp*`, as.vector(i), value = NA) :
x[.] <- val: x is “ngTMatrix”, val not in {TRUE, FALSE} is coerced; NA |--> TRUE
```

Then tried to identify redundant rules

```
redundant <- colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm=T) >= 1
```

Finally pruned rules

```
rules.pruned = rules.sorted[!redundant]
```

But while inspecting it showing nothing

```
inspect(rules.pruned)
```

Even summary of rules.pruned showing "zero" 0 rules

```
summary(rules.pruned)
```

I guess the error mainly due to the warning during conversion of matrix lower triangle to NA values which showed a warning

How to overcome the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.subset()` returns since version 1.5-2 a sparse matrix (see package [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/news.html)). If you want to use your code then you need to use:

```
subset.matrix <- is.subset(rules.sorted, rules.sorted, sparse = FALSE)
```

however, that is very inefficient and only works for very small rule sets. Use `is.redundant()` instead to find redundant rules.

Comment: Thank you vary much sir. sparse = FALSE and is.redundant() both works well.  Thanks for giving your valuable time and suggestion. your kind assistance is highly appreciated. Thank you again